# How to Find the Medoid of a Set in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, graph, average

I am trying to calculate the [medoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medoid) in matlab. However, i don't know how to do this. My dataset consists of multiple points of three-dimensional data (so a cloud of points in a system with three axes). The medoid is the point "*whose average dissimilarity to all the other objects in the cluster is minimal*" (wikipedia).

Does anyone know how to calculate the medoid in matlab?

---

*Btw.: as far as i know the [k-medoid algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7486-clustering-toolbox/content/FUZZCLUST/Kmedoid.m) cannot be used to calculate the medoid (efficiently), which is why i am looking for another way.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should not be difficult to do that once you provide the metric. Here is an implementation for scalars:

```
     function m = medoid(set,metric)
          [X,Y] = meshgrid(set,set); %Create all possible pairs
          dist = metric(X,Y);  %Run metric

          %Each distance is calculated twice, that doesn't matter. 
          %Also addition of zeros doesn't matter because we are looking for minimum.
          totalDist = mean(dist,1); 

          [~,i] = min(totalDist);
          m = set(i);
     end
```

And the use case:

```
metric = @(x,y) ( abs(x-y));
m = medoid([1 2 3 3 3 3 3], metric)
```

You can extend it to vectors, I will leave it as exercise for the reader. (Or someone who wants to add an improved answer).

Comment: In your example you are using 1d data, right? How would this work for 3d data (with x,y,z values)?

Comment: @SamuelKiely, It will not work. I wrote it to give a general direction.