# Correct use of pdist in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, point-clouds

I have a point-cloud, for which i want to calculate the distance between all individual points in Matlab (preferably without duplicates).

The matrix with the coordinates is formatted as: `points [ p x n x d ]`. Where `p = 1` (for now), n is as large as the number of points and d as large as the number of dimensions (3 in this case).

This is the data i have:

- `points(:,:,1) = 1 2 3`
- `points(:,:,2) = 4 5 6`
- `points(:,:,3) = 7 8 9`

So i have three points in three dimensions. Now using pdist, i have tried to calculate the euclidian distance between each point using `distances = pdist(points(:,1:3));` and `distances = pdist(X(:,:,1:3));` But both just return an empty matrix.

Does anyone know how to use `pdist` to calculate these distances? It should return 3 distances, instead of 0, but i must be doing something wrong.

---

*Btw. this question is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483363/simplifying-the-use-of-meshgrid-in-matlab) one. I asked it in the comments at first, but thought it deserved a new question because it is a considerable expansion of the original question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
distances = pdist(squeeze(X(:,:,1:3)));
```

or the transpose of `squeeze(...)` if that isn't correct.